# How to use join query for 4 tables in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following tables  4 models

```
class ItemCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_point
end

class ItemPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :item_codes
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :prodcut_category
  has_many :item_points
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :items
end
```

Now I have to find **item_codes** details using **product_category** for this I used inner join. Here is mysql query

```
SELECT *
FROM `item_codes` utc
INNER JOIN item_points rtp ON rtp.id = utc.item_point_id
INNER JOIN items ri ON ri.id = rtp.item_id
INNER JOIN product_catagories rpc ON rpc.id = ri.product_catagory_id
WHERE rpc.id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now I have to write the same query in the Acitve record format.

```
ItemCode.joins(:item_point).joins(:item).joins(:product_catagory).where("product_catagories.id = 1")
```

getting following error

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'item_points' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

So how can write given query in the Active record format.

**EDIT**

**product_catagories**

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at           | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at           | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| scheme_id            | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**item_points**

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**items**

+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+------------

```
----+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at                 | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                 | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_catagory_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**item_codes**

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_point_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you provide your table structure?

Comment: @I-am-simple-user, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ItemCode.joins(item_point: {item: :product_category}).where(product_category: {id: 1})
```

Let me simplify the **Joining Tables**:

> When you have **direct relation**:

```
# item_code belongs_to item_point
ItemCode.joins(:item_point) 

# ItemPoint has_many item_codes & belongs_to item
ItemPoint.joins(:item_codes, :item)
```

> When you have **indirect / nested relation**:

```
# ItemCode belongs_to item_point, item_point belongs_to item
ItemCode.joins(item_point: :item) 

# ItemCode belongs_to item_point, item_point belongs_to item, item belongs_to product_category 
ItemCode.joins(item_point: {item: :product_category})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UniqueItemCode.joins(item_points: [{ items: :product_catagories }]).where(product_catagory: {id: 1})
```